# Copy files to external storage using SAF

Tags: android

I'm trying to copy some files from my App's internal folder to the external memory of an android device.
I'm using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for the user to select the desired destination folder, in 'to', and have a list of Uri for the files I want to copy 'from', what's the best way to do it?

I tried:

```
public void copyFiles(ArrayList <Uri>from, Uri to)
{
    for (Uri u:from
         ) {
        try {
            File f = new File(u.getPath());
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(f);

            File d = new File(to.getPath(), f.getName());
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(d);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.e(TAG,ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception complaining the destination file does not exist: `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`.
Am I missing some step?

Comment: Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: We cannot see what you have in 'to'. Anyway you can not use the File class for SAF destinations. If source files come from apps internal storage you do not need an uri list. Just a string file paths list will do.

Comment: @blackapps 'to' contains the Uri returned by the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent. Likely your right, I don't need the source files Uris, I do have the full paths from the internal storage, I converted them to URI's just for ease of opening the FileInputStream, but my issue is actually creating the output stream, not the input.

Comment: OK, I think my issue is in the intent. Should I use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE or ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT? The objective is to allow the app user to copy files from the app directory to the external memory, and Vice-versa. I have the need to import/export definition files as well as some files automatically by the app.

For now I'm just focusing in the export part, as I believe the import should be easier, but I will need to export several files at a time.

Comment: You will use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and then create new files there. First just try to create a file there with DocumentFile.createFile(). Pretty basic. Dont use File class. Use DocumentFile class.

Comment: `'to' contains the Uri returned by the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent. ` Well tell the value of `uri.toString()`. Also tell the value of `u.getPath()` in `File f = new File(u.getPath());` and look at `file.getAbsolutePath()` (lLog.d() them all) and see that it delivers an impossible file system path.

Comment: to: "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADocuments"
u.getPath(): "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<myapp>/files/myfile.cfg - this is correct, I get the full path via native code.

to.getPath(): "/tree/primary:Documents"  - could this be the issue??? Should I use DocumentFile to create the file?
f.getName(): "myfile.cfg"

d.getAbsolutePath(): "/tree/primary:Documents/myfile.cfg"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248386/discussion-between-nuno-v-and-blackapps).